# Invalid column name table_Id using Code First EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Getting a exception thrown with error

```
Invalid column name 'Person_Id'.
```

It looks like the Code First is trying to create this column since it can't find it but this is a very basic model with no FKs so I don't see why I'm having this issue when calling SaveChanges()

I can use EF to get, update, and delete records from this table but not create a new record.

I also have another entity that is basically the same but with a different name and no issue with any CRUD operation on that one.

Here's my DBContext

```
public class EFContext : DbContext
{
    public EFContext() : base("DataContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<EFContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

My SQL Table

```
CREATE Person [dbo].[Person](
    [PersonId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([PersonId] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My Model

```
public class Person: ModelBase
{
    [Column("PersonId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: personid or person_id

Comment: @mohan111 The actual column is named PersonId but the error message is saying Person_Id. From what I've read that because EF can't find this column and tried to create it

Comment: You can show all tables that relate Person table.